# Cached Jquery selector behavior that I do not understand

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following code why am I getting different values for `a` and `b`? I would have thought they would return the same thing:

```
(function() {
    var a = $('#foo');

    var Test = function(){
    console.log(a); //outputs 'jQuery()'
    var b = $('#foo');
    console.log(b); //outputs 'jQuery(select#foo)' which is what I want
    };
})();
```

This question stems from me trying to stick frequently used selectors into vars. Originally I was doing it in each method (like I did with `var b` in the above example) but then I found I needed to use the selectors in multiple methods so I moved the assignment out to be available (or so I thought) to all of the methods in that anonymous function. As you can see, it does not work. Why is this?

EDIT: this code is loaded by a method that is triggered by a click. The id foo is present at page load and is not dynamically set or changed.

Comment: In my actual code it is a function that is called as part of a data validation method when a form is submitted. After page load at any rate.

Comment: But now that I think about it, the anonymous function itself is probably not loading at exactly the right time. It is loaded by a plugin but must be loading before the page finishes (thus `#foo` isn't available). Then, `Test()` is called after page load via a click so naturally it works. That helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the code isn't called until after your page finishes loading!

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Also, of course, you'll want to be careful about caching things that might be changed on the page by other parts of your client-side application.

Comment: It is called after page load. The ID being used is set in the html... it is not changed or dynamic in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Just to improve on the previous answer - b is only evaluated when you call the Test function, probably once the page is loaded. Cache the selectors inside document ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var a = $('#foo');
 });
```

I only cache selectors when I'm using the same selector inside a block of code. I use the $variable naming convention for this:

```
var $divs = $('div');
```

You can also chain functions together to avoid having to cache the selector:

```
$('div').append('hello world').addclass('hello').show();
```

Comment: I would say that is the most likely culprit. Putting your code in the $(document).ready() event ensures that the DOM will be accessible when that code is run, and that the jQuery object will find an element.